# How to replace any string value of pandas dataframewith 1

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
A     B     C     D
0    abc    0    cdf
abf   0     0    afg
```

And I want to replace any string value with 1.

The expected outcome should look like:

```
A     B     C     D
0     1     0     1
1     0     0     1
```

Any help on how to do this is appreciated..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The safe way

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors = 'coerce').fillna(1)
Out[217]: 
     A    B  C    D
0  0.0  1.0  0  1.0
1  1.0  0.0  0  1.0
```

And for the show case work

```
(~df.isin([0,'0'])).astype(int)
Out[221]: 
   A  B  C  D
0  0  1  0  1
1  1  0  0  1
```